# Attacking a grappled foe

Tags: dnd-3.5e

When you attack a foe grappled by one of your allies, do you have a chance of hitting your ally instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only with Ranged Attacks**

Rules Compendium (p. 61) explains it:

> Those not engaged in a grapple can attack those engaged in a grapple.
>   Grapplers take the aforementioned penalties to AC. If you make a
>   ranged attack against a grappler while not engaged in the grapple, you
>   roll randomly to see which grappler your attack strikes.

Melee attacks are safe. In fact they're probably easier, due to the penalties taken to defense while grappling.

How you determine who you hit with a ranged attack is up to the DM to determine, but it's random. Personally, I just roll an appropriate die (for two grapplers I use odds/evens, players choice which one they get).

([This is also in the SRD, as a footnote on the table about favorable conditions for the defender.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm#favorableandUnfavorableConditions) The Rules Compendium has a better explanation of the same rule.)

**Pathfinder - No Attacks**

This changed in Pathfinder to remove the risk for ranged attacks. [You can attack into a grapple safely.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Modifiers)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I gotta show this to my DM. I'm tired of hitting/getting hit by allies because of this. He insists that melee strikes works 50% chance to hit any of the grapplers.

Comment: @Azrael Happy to help :)

Comment: Does the same rules apply to Pathfinder system? I forgot to ask.

Comment: @Azrael I'll check. Please edit your question to add that part. :)

Comment: @Tridus no need to look. There is no possibility of hitting your ally in Pathfinder, even with ranged attacks. This is the corresponding table. The footnote simply does not exist any more http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Modifiers

Comment: @Tridus In PF, you don't even move into the square of the creature you're grappling; conceptually, it's not as up-close as it was in 3.5.